# How to make a control scale proportionately with its contents

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, surface, viewbox

I am using WPF to create an interactive touch-based application. The application uses `ScatterViewItem` objects to hold two scrollable menus inside, a main menu and a sub-menu side by side and display various content depending on the items selected.

By default, the `ScatterViewItem` is scalable using touch gestures, but the problem is that only the container itself grows/shrinks in size, while the items simply move further apart or closer together inside it.

Example:
[image]

What I wish for to happen is for the container and everything inside it to scale proportionately, just like an image would, for example.

I've tried using a `ViewBox` to wrap all the contents inside, but this caused a host of new problems:

1. The once scrollable menus (`SurfaceScrollViewer`) are now automatically scaled so that they fit entirely inside the container. This is bad since the individual item size changes depending on the amount of items in the sub-menu. I need them to stay scrollable, and for the same amount of items (roughly 3x3) to be able to  fit in the container no matter the total count.
2. `TextBox` controls now change their font sizes depending on the content length to fit the text in one line. I wish for the font size to stay uniform across all items, wrapping around to the next line if necessary.

What would be best approach for this? Should I just use some kind of binding to have a fixed proportion between each object's dimensions and its parent container's dimensions?

I have very limited C#/WPF experience and a tight schedule so any suggestions and/or examples would be very welcome.

Comment: Can you post the xaml you currently have? Could you try to set the properties `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAligment` of the `ScatterViewItem`s to a value of `Stretch`?

Comment: Most of the controls are actually implemented in C# in the code behind.
Basically the hierarchy is: `ScatterViewItem` -> `Border` -> `Grid` -> and both menus are `SurfaceScrollViewer`s.

I have set the alignment properties as you suggested, but haven't noticed any difference. Or did you mean for me to try that with the `ViewBox` included under the `ScatterViewItem` ?